# Passing Puppeteer log result into form input field

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Using Puppeteer I can extract data and print that data on my Terminal:

Output:

```
{
  name: 'Deep into the Jungle',
  price: '$24'
}
```

I also know I can print only name, using the following code:

```
console.log(result.name);
```

Output:

```
{
  'Deep into the Jungle'
}
```

I'm trying to pass the result.name to my form field on my website. But unsuccessfully.

I already know the form field name and can succesfully put data manually using this:

```
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', el => el.value = 'my-manually-written-name-goes-here');
```

Since I know the correct field imput name and I know what value I want to pass, logically something like this should work:

```
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', el => el.value = result.name);
```

But it didn't pass anything. A blank.

I have also tried the following:

```
await page.type('input[name=wc_name]', result.name);
```

A blank as well, nothing passed.

So my question is:

1. What I'm missing? I'm not a coder, maybe I'm just missing `''` or `""`
2. Is it actually possible to pass the result value (as soon as you grab it) into the input field?
   Maybe I need to store the values using `fs` into the text file first, and only then (using `fs` again) grab them from the file and pass to the input field on my website?

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is enough to fix but worth trying. `result` variable is declared in the Node.js context. To transfer it into a callback evaluated in the browser context, you need to add it as an argument:

```js
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', (el, name) => { el.value = name; }, result.name);
```

Comment: Last quick question, how do I do the same for this: await page.type("[class='ql-editor ql-blank']", 'mypricevalue');
It's a non input. Value: result.price

Comment: If there is no callback evaluated in the browser context, Node.js context variables should work. However, the `page.type()` works only with input type elements. It is worth posting a separate question with a more detailed description: what element you need to change and in what way.

Comment: will do. Thanks for your help!